# php - start every page with a front controller..-

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to load some setting in every page of a web site, then I'm configuring a front controller in this way

**htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule . front-controller.php [L]
```

and this **front-controller**

```
session_start();
require 'content/mysql.php';

[initialize variable]

[initialize function]
```

then, how to load request page?

**EDIT**

Tried to include `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` but pages are loaded without css / js

With inspect page I have

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:
```

**EDIT 2**

Changed from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

to

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and inspect error seems to be resolved, but page is always loaded without stylesheet

Comment: Doesn't work can mean anything. What happens concretely? What are the error messages? Are there any static web pages or PHP scripts at `DOCUMENT_ROOT/REQUEST_URI`?

Comment: pages are loaded without css / js

Comment: So the main HTML pages are loaded properly, but CSS and Javascript files are not loaded?

Comment: Yes, the error in the first post

Comment: You could add your solution as an answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem adding this line in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule  ^(css|fonts|functions|js|media)($|/) - [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following to not rewrite existing files to front-controller.php:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

This will only match the RewriteRule if the requested file or directory does not exist based on URI.